# How to change comment count in previous page after updateing in current page in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, comments

I am trying to increase the comment count in previous page after commenting in the current page whent it posted successfully. So that I can see increased comment number without refreshing the page when I press back button. Just like facebook. But I have no idea how to change the state of that particular widget. So please help.

Comment: i think you can use provider or bloc to achieve that thing but you also have to change a lot of thing

Comment: Is it possible to change the widget from previous page using redux?

Comment: i am not familiar with redux but you have to create new object to access data in redux, so i think that it may be not possible.